# Azure AAD Token request on postman using App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, bearer-token

I am trying to use an App Registration to get a Token Bearer, but I don't have idea on how to do that using App registration. I have this in postman:

[image]

Comment: What problems are you having now ?

Comment: What error was reported?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, after you register an application (web,mobile app...) in Identity Server (Microsoft in this case), you will get `client_id` and `client_secret` --> This is `grant-types: client-credentials` https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/

If you want to use `grant-types: password`, you also need `client_id` and `client_secret` to ask for access_token. https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is not assigned, and you need to select the `Content-Type` as: `x-www-form-urlencoded`, the [complete request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request) is as follows:

[image]